# Decay length and COM energy

Tags: particle-physics

Suppose you collide two particles and produce a new unstable one.

Does its decay length (i.e. the distance it will travel) depend on the COM energy at which it is produced? assuming that the COM energy is larger than it's mass

Comment: Produce more than one particles, one of them unstable, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern colliders produce particles travelling at speeds very close to the speed of light, so the distance a particle travels from the collision point will be:

$$ s \approx c \gamma \tau $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) and $\tau$ is the particle lifetime in its rest frame. The particle lifetime $\tau$ is not dependent upon the COM energy since it's a fundamental property of the particle, however the Lorentz factor will increase with increasing COM energy. This is simply because increasing COM energy will increase the kinetic energy, and therefore velocity, of the particles created in the collision.

It isn't quite as simple as I've suggested since increasing COM energy may produce more particles so the increased energy is shared amongst an increased number of particles, so in practice the relationship between distance travelled and COM energy will not be a simple one. However there will certainly be some change in the distance travelled with energy.